# How to display data from cell on the same row but one column over from the first empty cell in a column

Tags: excel

I am creating a reading list that has the day in column a and the required reading in column b for that day. in column c I write the day the reading is completed.

I want to have a cell display the required reading from the row that has the first blank cell in column c.

I hope this makes sense.

I know I'll have to use indirect, because I have a cell with the required reading from today in another cell using =INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(TODAY(),A:A))

Answer (score 1):

The way I understood your question is:
 - You have **dates** in `Column A`
 - `Column B` has corresponding **readings**
 - `Column C` is reading **completion date** that can be blank
So what you want is the **first reading** from `Column B` for dates in `Column A` which are same as today's date where `Column C` is **blank**

If my understanding is correct the following array formula should work for you.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$21,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$21=TODAY())*($C$2:$C$21=""),0))
```

This is an array formula you'll have to commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

See the image for reference (rows with matching date in `Column A` i.e. equal to today's date are **highlighted**):

[image]

This result can also be achieved using your formula with some change as:

```
=INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(TODAY(),(A1:A21)*(ISBLANK(C1:C21)),0))
```

Again this is an **array formula**.

But as @Gary'sStudent mentioned in his answer, its always better to avoid `INDIRECT` function.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the row containing the first blank in column **C**:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(C:C),0,0),0)
```

So to get the equivalent cell in column **B**, use:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(C:C),0,0),0))
```

[image]

Thus we avoid *INDIRECT()*.  See:

[Daily Dose](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2016/04/25/excels-most-evil-functions/)